# Why it is showing error Forbidden, You do not have permission to access this document

Tags: codeigniter, windows-hosting

There is one website hosted on paralles pannel say www.mydomain.com
I have developed one another webpotal in codeigniter and wanted to host in a directory under mydomain.com
say www.mydomain.com/codeigniterportal

I have created a database and transferred the file in a directory.

Now, When i try to access the www.mydomain.com/codeigniterportal it showing me an error

Forbidden, You do not have permission to access this document.

.htaccess file contains

```
 <IfModule authz_core_module>
     Require all denied
 </IfModule>
  <IfModule !authz_core_module>
   Allow from all
  </IfModule>
```

Please help

Comment: check the permissions for that folder.

Comment: Its read, write, Execute

Comment: please paste your htaccess file.

Comment: .htaccess

<IfModule authz_core_module>
 Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
 Allow from all
</IfModule>

Comment: please update the question with .htaccess, it is difficult to understand in comments.